# how to create a mutlilingual route in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual, zend-route

I need a route in Zend Framework that maps the following uri's to EventController > indexAction.

```
:lang/programma/:name/:page
:lang/programme/:name/:page
:lang/event/:name/:page
```

The second parameter has to be "**programma**" OR "**programme**" OR "**event**".
 I could simply create 3 different routes for this but I think it is possible to do this in just one.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Zend_Translate` and `Zend_Controller_Router_Route::setDefaultTranslator()`. A detailed description can be found in the [Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).